# ¿Como podría modificar este codigo(de ser posible) para que imprima un diccionario en lugar de una lista en pantalla?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero que imprima como clave el número ingresado por el usuario y como valor su duplicado.

Ejemplo:

`{
   "2":"4", 
   "3":"6", 
   "4":"8"
}`

```
def duplicando():   
    nums = []
    for i in range(4):
        valor = int(input("Ingrese un valor a duplicar: "))
        nums.append(valor)

    resultado = list(map(lambda x:x*2, nums))
    print(resultado)

duplicando()
```

Comment: ¿Quieres `{"2": "4",  "3": "6",  "4":"8"}` o `{"dos":"4", "tres":"6", "cuatro":"8"}`, porque el primero es trivial, el segundo se complica un poco si el usuario está habilitado a introducir cualquier entero....

Comment: Si así {"2": "4", "3": "6", "4":"8"} quiero. Me equivoque en la descripción.

Comment: En vez de una lista crea un diccionario y luego simplemente crea las parejas, (aprovecha el ciclo para el cálculo y te evitas volver a iterar) `nums[valor] = valor * 2`, o si quieres cadenas no hagas el casting en el `input` y haz `nums[valor] = str(int(valor) * 2)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes declarar un **diccionario** en vez de un vector de números, y luego establecer como clave del diccionario el valor ingresado por el usuario, y como valor del diccionario el doble.

La solución quedaría así:

```
def duplicando():   
    nums = {}
    for i in range(2):
        valor = int(input("Ingrese un valor a duplicar: "))
        nums[valor] = valor*2
    print(nums)

duplicando()
```

Salida obtenida:

```
Ingrese un valor a duplicar: 1
Ingrese un valor a duplicar: 2
Ingrese un valor a duplicar: 3
Ingrese un valor a duplicar: 4
{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8}
```